# CSS: How to build a vertical separator with margin on its top and bottom?

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to build the vertical separator in the below images (I mean the separator between the camera icon and scanner icon). I tried to use border, but border seems has no property to set margin on itself. Does anyone know how to realize that? I don't mean just to insert a vertical line, but a line with a margin on it's top and bottom.

[vertical separator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49k5o.png)

[image]

Comment: You could use a pseudo-element with a smaller height.

Comment: You use div ? Ul ? Dl ?Some code ?

Comment: You can use :after pseudoclass:

.mydiv:after {
 content: "|";
}

Comment: Please add your html structure

Comment: Duplicate of this? There are suitable answers apart from the accepted answer. stackoverflow.com/questions/3148415/how-to-make-a-vertical-line-in-html

Comment: Basically, research "CSS pseudo-elements". I'd just right click and inspect element and learn it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use margin around each icon, this way you can create the border and have the spacing around the icon.

Here is a pen for you

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKNdwj

```
li { width: 50px; float: left; list-style: none;  border-right: 1px solid #ccc; display: block; padding: 0px 5px;  margin: 10px 5px; }
li.last { border: none; margin-right: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

borders are a good solution for this.

```
div {
    margin: 100px;
    padding:50px;
    border-left:1px solid black;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZvBMb

Ideally, though, you'd apply this border to a pseudo :before or :after element